# Weak convergence of measures, weak star topology and compactness

Tags: real-analysis, probability

Since the space of finite measures can be identified with the dual of the space of continuous functions, we know that the weak convergence of measure coincides with the weak star convergence in the space of contnuous functions.
We also knwo that in general this weak star convergence induces a weak star topology which are in general not metrizable. In particular the relatively compactness property and the compactness property are not the same in general.

Is it true also in the specific case of the weak convergence of measure or does the weak convergence of measure induce a star metric which induces a weak star topology?
In this case the relatively compactness property and the compactness property are the same?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy%E2%80%93Prokhorov_metric

Comment: Thank you very much!